# how to set horizontal Coordinator Layout with Recycler View

Tags: xml, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

**i need to implement my layout horizontal, but right now it is in linear layout, i do not where is my mistake but i need your help to solve this issue**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/card_view_recycler_list"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your java class put this code:

```
 LinearLayoutManager lManager = new 
    LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    lManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(lManager);
```